# Disable Screen Lock on Android JB 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

OS: Android JB 4.2.2.

The application that I am working on doesn't have a touch screen (This is **not** a handheld Mobile Application). Therefore I want to change screen lock to NONE (Settings > Security > Screen Security > Screen lock). Essentially disable the screen lock.

I find that most the setting are stored in com.android.provider.settings/database directory in settings.db

Can anyone shed some light on were the Settings > Security > Screen Security > Screen lock variable might be stored?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adb shell sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db "update locksettings set value='1' where name='lockscreen.disabled';"